# Can not import a module when run the flask server using the flask run command

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to flask framework and I want to write a simple flask app that uses another python module (`librosa` package). I have successfully installed `librosa` in the same virtual environment that I have installed `flask` and I can easily import it in the python interpreter. Here is the python script.

```
# app.py
from flask import Flask
import librosa

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The problem is that when I want to run the flask app using the `flask run` command (after setting `export FLASK_APP=app.py`) I get the `ModuleNotFoundError` error as follows:

```
Error: While importing "app", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/masoud/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/masoud/projects/my_projects/seperator_rewriten/app.py", line 2, in <module>
    import librosa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'librosa'
```

The strange thing is that there is no import error when I run the flask server using `python app.py` command.

Answer (score 2):

This may be the solution to your problem:

```
python -m flask run
```

The reason is that `flask run` may use the python executable somewhere else, not the virtual environment you created for the project.

You can add these lines of code in your script:

```
import sys
import flask

print(sys.executable)
print(flask.__version__)
```

And then you can check the python executable path using `python app.py` and `flask run`.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using an IDE such as pycharm, then you may need to install it from the terminal in the IDE itself, not cmd

Comment: So what is the problem? I want to be able to run the app from both Pycharm and the command line? Is this due to the improper setting of my python interpreter in Pycharm or it is because of something else that happens behind in the flask run command?

Comment: you can type pip install librosa in the pycharm terminal